# Regular Expression - Replace hex character codes with coresponding character

Tags: regex, hex, textmate

Is it possible to replace hex character codes with coresponding character in TextMate or some similar text-editor for OS X?

Search Pattern:

```
=([A-F0-9]{2})
```

Replace Pattern:

```
\x$1
```

Source Text:

```
=E5=E4=F6=C5=C4=D6
```

Desired Result for replaced text:

```
åäöÅÄÖ
```

I've tried lots of differnet variations of $1 and \1 with differnet escapes and also octal syntax. But nothing produced desired result.

Comment: I strongly doubt there is a text editor with an inbuilt feature like this. You may write your own plug-in or Python script or whatever extension the editor of your choice provides.

Comment: Sad. Though it seems like TextMate can handle replacing of hex codes up to 79, i.e. \x79.